# How can I switch the View directly with a function call in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, view, swiftui

Hey I am new to Swift and SwiftUI and I would like to know how I can switch between Views

As you can see in the code below I have made a splashscreen animation and I would like my App to switch into the next View when the state "endSplash" is true, but I do not know how to achieve this goal. I have read on how to change the View with a NavigationView and a NavigationLink but the problem is I do not want the user to press for example on a button/text I want to switch the View directly. Is there like a function I can call to change the View directly (like in Android Studio where I can just start a new Intent) ?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var animate = false
    @State var endSplash = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
        ZStack{
            Color("Primary")
            
            Image("LBig").resizable().renderingMode(.original).aspectRatio(contentMode: animate ? .fill : .fit)
                .frame(width: animate ? nil : 85, height: animate ? nil: 85)
                .colorInvert().scaleEffect(animate ? 3 : 1).frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        }.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all).onAppear(perform: {
            animateSplash()
        }).opacity(endSplash ? 0:1)
    }
}
    func animateSplash(){
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5){
            withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.45)){
                animate.toggle()
            }
            withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.35)){
                endSplash.toggle()
                //Switch to another View here I guess ?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a `Bool` all you need is a conditional.

If you want it in the Navigation Stack (with a Back button) use the `NavigationLink` constructor with `isActive` and use your `Bool` to make the `View` active.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwitchScreen: View {
    @State var animate = false
    @State var endSplash = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            switch endSplash{
            case false:
                ZStack{
                    
                    Color.blue
                    
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark").resizable().renderingMode(.original).aspectRatio(contentMode: animate ? .fill : .fit)
                        .frame(width: animate ? nil : 85, height: animate ? nil: 85)
                        .colorInvert().scaleEffect(animate ? 3 : 1).frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                    
                    
                }.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all).onAppear(perform: {
                    animateSplash()
                }).opacity(endSplash ? 0:1)
            case true:
                Text("Done")
            }
        }
    }
    func animateSplash(){
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5){
            withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.45)){
                animate.toggle()
            }
            withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.35)){
                endSplash.toggle()
                //Switch to another View here I guess ?
            }
        }
    }
}
struct SwitchScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwitchScreen()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was searching for

Answer (score 1):

I have make some edits on your code, hope it helps.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var animate = false
    @State var endSplash = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack{
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: YourDestinationView(),
                    isActive: $endSplash
                ) { EmptyView() }
                Color("Primary")
                
                Image("LBig").resizable().renderingMode(.original).aspectRatio(contentMode: animate ? .fill : .fit)
                    .frame(width: animate ? nil : 85, height: animate ? nil: 85)
                    .colorInvert().scaleEffect(animate ? 3 : 1).frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
            }.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all).onAppear(perform: {
                animateSplash()
            }).opacity(endSplash ? 0:1)
        }
    }
    func animateSplash(){
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5){
            withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.45)){
                animate.toggle()
            }
            withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.35)){
                endSplash.toggle()
                //Switch to another View here I guess ?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this way you just need to set what is your destination view, and at the end of the animation it will be navigate to the destination.